# Replace/remove all diacritics and converting different letters to Latin alphabet in multiple spreadsheet columns (multidimensional array)

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

> Attention: if you read the question and are going to use the `defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap` in
> the future → I analyzed the name of all professional football athletes
> and added some letters that do not exist in the [original map](http://web.archive.org/web/20120918093154/http://lehelk.com/2011/05/06/script-to-remove-diacritics/), so it is
> modified for my use, test it first and see if that way too it's ok for
> you!

Currently (the code bellow works) to work with one column or multiple columns I use `.join('♠')` and after I remove the diacritics and convert the letters to the Latin alphabet, I separate again using `.split('♠')`, but this causes a slowness in the process, I would like some help to find a more agile method.

Example array collect in spreadsheet via:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(get_range).getValues();
```

```js
var diacriticsMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++) {
  var letters = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters;
  for (var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
    diacriticsMap[letters[j]] = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base;
  }
}

function remove_all_diacritics(sheet_name, get_range, row_set, col_set) {
//  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheet_name);
//  var values = sheet.getRange(get_range).getValues();
  var values = [['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'], ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'], ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'], ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'], ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'], ['æ', 'ø', 'å', 'á'], ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'], ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'], ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'], ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ], [, , , ]]

  var ct = 0;
  while (values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "") {
    ct++;
  }
  var values = values.slice(0, ct);
  var joiners = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    joiners.push([values[i].join('♠')])
  }
  var new_values = joiners.map(([v]) => [v.toString() != "" ? v.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, a => diacriticsMap[a] || a) : ""]);

  nv_arrays = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < new_values.length; i++) {
    nv_arrays.push(new_values[i][0].split('♠'))
  }
//  sheet.getRange(row_set, col_set, nv_arrays.length, nv_arrays[0].length).setValues(nv_arrays);
  console.log(nv_arrays)
}

function rad() {
  remove_all_diacritics('NoDiacritics', 'A1:D', 1, 6)
}
rad()
```

```html
<script>
var defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
  {'base':'A', 'letters':'\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F\u018F\u0410'},
  {'base':'AA','letters':'\uA732'},
  {'base':'AE','letters':'\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2'},
  {'base':'AO','letters':'\uA734'},
  {'base':'AU','letters':'\uA736'},
  {'base':'AV','letters':'\uA738\uA73A'},
  {'base':'AY','letters':'\uA73C'},
  {'base':'B', 'letters':'\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181'},
  {'base':'C', 'letters':'\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E'},
  {'base':'D', 'letters':'\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779\u00D0'},
  {'base':'DZ','letters':'\u01F1\u01C4'},
  {'base':'Dz','letters':'\u01F2\u01C5'},
  {'base':'E', 'letters':'\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E\u0415'},
  {'base':'F', 'letters':'\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B'},
  {'base':'G', 'letters':'\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E'},
  {'base':'H', 'letters':'\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D'},
  {'base':'I', 'letters':'\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197'},
  {'base':'J', 'letters':'\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248'},
  {'base':'K', 'letters':'\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2'},
  {'base':'L', 'letters':'\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780'},
  {'base':'LJ','letters':'\u01C7'},
  {'base':'Lj','letters':'\u01C8'},
  {'base':'M', 'letters':'\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C\u041C'},
  {'base':'N', 'letters':'\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4'},
  {'base':'NJ','letters':'\u01CA'},
  {'base':'Nj','letters':'\u01CB'},
  {'base':'O', 'letters':'\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C\u041E'},
  {'base':'OI','letters':'\u01A2'},
  {'base':'OO','letters':'\uA74E'},
  {'base':'OU','letters':'\u0222'},
  {'base':'OE','letters':'\u008C\u0152'},
  {'base':'oe','letters':'\u009C\u0153'},
  {'base':'P', 'letters':'\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754'},
  {'base':'Q', 'letters':'\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A'},
  {'base':'R', 'letters':'\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782'},
  {'base':'S', 'letters':'\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784'},
  {'base':'T', 'letters':'\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786'},
  {'base':'Thor','letters':'\u00DE'},
  {'base':'TZ','letters':'\uA728'},
  {'base':'U', 'letters':'\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244'},
  {'base':'V', 'letters':'\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245'},
  {'base':'VY','letters':'\uA760'},
  {'base':'W', 'letters':'\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72'},
  {'base':'X', 'letters':'\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C'},
  {'base':'Y', 'letters':'\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE'},
  {'base':'Z', 'letters':'\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762'},
  {'base':'a', 'letters':'\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250\u0259'},
  {'base':'aa','letters':'\uA733'},
  {'base':'ae','letters':'\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3'},
  {'base':'ao','letters':'\uA735'},
  {'base':'au','letters':'\uA737'},
  {'base':'av','letters':'\uA739\uA73B'},
  {'base':'ay','letters':'\uA73D'},
  {'base':'b', 'letters':'\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253'},
  {'base':'c', 'letters':'\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184\u0441'},
  {'base':'d', 'letters':'\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A'},
  {'base':'dz','letters':'\u01F3\u01C6'},
  {'base':'e', 'letters':'\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD'},
  {'base':'f', 'letters':'\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C'},
  {'base':'g', 'letters':'\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F'},
  {'base':'h', 'letters':'\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265'},
  {'base':'hv','letters':'\u0195'},
  {'base':'i', 'letters':'\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131\u0456'},
  {'base':'j', 'letters':'\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249'},
  {'base':'k', 'letters':'\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3'},
  {'base':'l', 'letters':'\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747'},
  {'base':'lj','letters':'\u01C9'},
  {'base':'m', 'letters':'\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F'},
  {'base':'n', 'letters':'\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5'},
  {'base':'nj','letters':'\u01CC'},
  {'base':'o', 'letters':'\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275\u00F0'},
  {'base':'oi','letters':'\u01A3'},
  {'base':'ou','letters':'\u0223'},
  {'base':'oo','letters':'\uA74F'},
  {'base':'p','letters':'\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755'},
  {'base':'q','letters':'\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759'},
  {'base':'r','letters':'\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783'},
  {'base':'s','letters':'\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B'},
  {'base':'t','letters':'\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787'},
  {'base':'thor','letters':'\u00FE'},
  {'base':'tz','letters':'\uA729'},
  {'base':'u','letters': '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289\u03CB'},
  {'base':'v','letters':'\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C'},
  {'base':'vy','letters':'\uA761'},
  {'base':'w','letters':'\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73'},
  {'base':'x','letters':'\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D'},
  {'base':'y','letters':'\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF'},
  {'base':'z','letters':'\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763'}
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use a simple recursive function  using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This maintains the initial structure of the multidimensional array without needing loops and all those array/string manipulations of `.join` ,`.split` and `.push`.

  ```
  const replace = (v) =>
    Array.isArray(v)
      ? v.map((v) => replace(v))
      : String(v).replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, (a) => diacriticsMap[a] || a);
  ```
- Use `const` and `let` as needed instead of declaring all variables as `var`. This helps the [javascript engine optimize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070631/v8-javascript-performance-implications-of-const-let-and-var) the memory and processing of such variables

```js
const defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap = [
  {
    base: 'A',
    letters:
      '\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F\u018F\u0410',
  },
  { base: 'AA', letters: '\uA732' },
  { base: 'AE', letters: '\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2' },
  { base: 'AO', letters: '\uA734' },
  { base: 'AU', letters: '\uA736' },
  { base: 'AV', letters: '\uA738\uA73A' },
  { base: 'AY', letters: '\uA73C' },
  {
    base: 'B',
    letters: '\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181',
  },
  {
    base: 'C',
    letters:
      '\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E',
  },
  {
    base: 'D',
    letters:
      '\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779\u00D0',
  },
  { base: 'DZ', letters: '\u01F1\u01C4' },
  { base: 'Dz', letters: '\u01F2\u01C5' },
  {
    base: 'E',
    letters:
      '\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E\u0415',
  },
  { base: 'F', letters: '\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B' },
  {
    base: 'G',
    letters:
      '\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E',
  },
  {
    base: 'H',
    letters:
      '\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D',
  },
  {
    base: 'I',
    letters:
      '\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197',
  },
  { base: 'J', letters: '\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248' },
  {
    base: 'K',
    letters:
      '\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2',
  },
  {
    base: 'L',
    letters:
      '\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780',
  },
  { base: 'LJ', letters: '\u01C7' },
  { base: 'Lj', letters: '\u01C8' },
  {
    base: 'M',
    letters: '\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C\u041C',
  },
  {
    base: 'N',
    letters:
      '\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4',
  },
  { base: 'NJ', letters: '\u01CA' },
  { base: 'Nj', letters: '\u01CB' },
  {
    base: 'O',
    letters:
      '\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C\u041E',
  },
  { base: 'OI', letters: '\u01A2' },
  { base: 'OO', letters: '\uA74E' },
  { base: 'OU', letters: '\u0222' },
  { base: 'OE', letters: '\u008C\u0152' },
  { base: 'oe', letters: '\u009C\u0153' },
  {
    base: 'P',
    letters: '\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754',
  },
  { base: 'Q', letters: '\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A' },
  {
    base: 'R',
    letters:
      '\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782',
  },
  {
    base: 'S',
    letters:
      '\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784',
  },
  {
    base: 'T',
    letters:
      '\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786',
  },
  { base: 'Thor', letters: '\u00DE' },
  { base: 'TZ', letters: '\uA728' },
  {
    base: 'U',
    letters:
      '\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244',
  },
  { base: 'V', letters: '\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245' },
  { base: 'VY', letters: '\uA760' },
  {
    base: 'W',
    letters: '\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72',
  },
  { base: 'X', letters: '\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C' },
  {
    base: 'Y',
    letters:
      '\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE',
  },
  {
    base: 'Z',
    letters:
      '\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762',
  },
  {
    base: 'a',
    letters:
      '\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250\u0259',
  },
  { base: 'aa', letters: '\uA733' },
  { base: 'ae', letters: '\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3' },
  { base: 'ao', letters: '\uA735' },
  { base: 'au', letters: '\uA737' },
  { base: 'av', letters: '\uA739\uA73B' },
  { base: 'ay', letters: '\uA73D' },
  {
    base: 'b',
    letters: '\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253',
  },
  {
    base: 'c',
    letters:
      '\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184\u0441',
  },
  {
    base: 'd',
    letters:
      '\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A',
  },
  { base: 'dz', letters: '\u01F3\u01C6' },
  {
    base: 'e',
    letters:
      '\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD',
  },
  { base: 'f', letters: '\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C' },
  {
    base: 'g',
    letters:
      '\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F',
  },
  {
    base: 'h',
    letters:
      '\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265',
  },
  { base: 'hv', letters: '\u0195' },
  {
    base: 'i',
    letters:
      '\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131\u0456',
  },
  { base: 'j', letters: '\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249' },
  {
    base: 'k',
    letters:
      '\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3',
  },
  {
    base: 'l',
    letters:
      '\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747',
  },
  { base: 'lj', letters: '\u01C9' },
  { base: 'm', letters: '\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F' },
  {
    base: 'n',
    letters:
      '\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5',
  },
  { base: 'nj', letters: '\u01CC' },
  {
    base: 'o',
    letters:
      '\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275\u00F0',
  },
  { base: 'oi', letters: '\u01A3' },
  { base: 'ou', letters: '\u0223' },
  { base: 'oo', letters: '\uA74F' },
  {
    base: 'p',
    letters: '\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755',
  },
  { base: 'q', letters: '\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759' },
  {
    base: 'r',
    letters:
      '\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783',
  },
  {
    base: 's',
    letters:
      '\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B',
  },
  {
    base: 't',
    letters:
      '\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787',
  },
  { base: 'thor', letters: '\u00FE' },
  { base: 'tz', letters: '\uA729' },
  {
    base: 'u',
    letters:
      '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289\u03CB',
  },
  { base: 'v', letters: '\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C' },
  { base: 'vy', letters: '\uA761' },
  {
    base: 'w',
    letters:
      '\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73',
  },
  { base: 'x', letters: '\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D' },
  {
    base: 'y',
    letters:
      '\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF',
  },
  {
    base: 'z',
    letters:
      '\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763',
  },
];

const diacriticsMap = {};
for (let i = 0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap.length; i++) {
  const letters = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].letters;
  for (let j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
    diacriticsMap[letters[j]] = defaultDiacriticsRemovalMap[i].base;
  }
}

function remove_all_diacritics(sheet_name, get_range, row_set, col_set) {
  //  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  //  const values = sheet.getRange(get_range).getValues();
  const values = [
    ['á', 'á', 'á', ''],
    ['á', 'b', 'á', 'á'],
    ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'],
    ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'],
    ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'],
    ['æ', 'ø', 'å', 'á'],
    ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'],
    ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'],
    ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'],
    ['á', 'á', 'á', 'á'],
    [, , ,],
    [, , ,],
    [, , ,],
    [, , ,],
    [, , ,],
    [, , ,],
    [, , ,],
    [, , ,],
    [, , ,],
    [, , ,],
  ];
  const replace = (v) =>
    Array.isArray(v)
      ? v.map((v) => replace(v))
      : String(v).replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, (a) => diacriticsMap[a] || a);
  //  sheet.getRange(row_set, col_set, nv_arrays.length, nv_arrays[0].length).setValues(nv_arrays);
  console.log(replace(values));
}

function rad() {
  remove_all_diacritics('NoDiacritics', 'A1:D', 1, 6);
}
rad();
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying an answer! I know some reasons but for the sake of others: can you please [edit] your answer to provide an explanation of why `const` and `let` should be used instead of `var`?